# Have a task copy all dependencies from another task in the same project?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have two tasks, with the same dependendencies.

Rather than writing every dependency twice, e.g.

```
A.dependsOn C
B.dependsOn C
...
```

Is there a way I can have B easily copy dependencies from A without having it actually depend on A? I don't want A to run before B or vice versa when I call one of the tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a collection of the tasks you want to depend on and use it as follows:

```
def commonDependencies = [
        C, D, E
]

A.dependsOn commonDependencies
B.dependsOn commonDependencies
```

Or you can do it from with the array of you `A` and `B` task as follows:

```
[A, B].each {task -> task.dependsOn C}
```

it iterates over the array and sets every element `dependsOn` property.